# Latop for Penetration Testing and Hacking

Tags: laptop

I'm looking for a laptop to be used for Penetration Testing.

Desired specs:

- 1 TB SSD
- 16+ GB RAM
- NVIDIA GTX 10 series 2+ GB (not a must but highly desirable)
- Wireless/Network card compatible with hacking software (including those in Kali Linux)

I don't have a clear budget but something around 600-1000 USD would probably be OK.

Comment: Going to be very difficult to find something @ $500 with a GTX 10 series....Do you need that kind of graphics power for Kali Linux?

Comment: I did some more research and raised my budget. Also, a GTX 10 isn't a must but I'm learning CUDA which seems to work best with an NVIDIA GTX.